# Calculate edge and plane of a box given its vertices

Tags: geometry

This seems to be a very simple problem that can be used in a SE interview, though I can't find its solution:

> Given 8 vertices of a box, find its plane and edge equations.

My solution is to choose any 3 points, then find the coplanar point.

- If the 4 other points lie on the same side, then the first 2 planes are formed.
- Otherwise (the plane cross the box), pick 2 points from the 4 coplanar points, and 2 points that are on the same side. The first 2 planes are also formed.

Whenever a new plane is found, picks 2 points, use the same side test to find the edge equation.

My solution uses too many `if` statements and checking (check if many points are on the same side, check if a formed plane is a duplicate of a found plane or not). Is there:

- a fast (like, a couple of matrix multiplications for vectorized fast), or
- a more straightforward, clever solution that can be explained to high school students?

Answer (score 2):

1. Pick any vertex $V$.
2. Calculate the vectors to the other 7 vertices.
3. Calculate the pairwise dot product of these 7 vectors, a set of 3 will be mutually perpendicular (the rest will be positive, can you show why)?
4. This determines the vertices connected to $V$, and their directional vectors.
5. The rest follows.

Comment: If 2 vectors are perpendicular, their dot product is zero. And the angle between any 2 vectors (formed the above way) is less than 90, so their dot products must be positive. However, I don't think it's faster than mine. Clumsy me thought that I have to check all 3-point-select combination, but it's not the case.

Comment: Is there a matrix solution? It could involve even more calculation, but I think vectorization will speed thing up dramatically.

Comment: @MinhNghĩa Once you know the neighbors of the chosen vertex, then you also have the three face normals that you need. Identify the opposite vertex and you have all you need to generate the face plane equations.